# DataTable column position is different than result set from db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I am getting my `ResultSet` (using `stored procedure`) in `DataTable` but strange thing is that `column` position get changed in `DataTable` then what is returned from `db`. Please look following images:
First image is result in `SSMS SQL query` returned, which is correct.
[image]

Second image is `DataTable` in code. How come the last tow columns change their position:
[image]

Last two columns are being generated using `pivot/unpivot`. See this fiddle for more understanding [query fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e685/46)

Regards,

Comment: It's likely that your data grid is listing the column names alphabetically, whereas SSMS is not.

Comment: But the position of columns get changed in DataTable which is not yet bind with grid.

Comment: Whether it's bound or not, my first guess is that whatever you're viewing it in is likely sorting the columns alphabetically. If you bind it to the actual data grid does it still show in that order?

Comment: Yes, it is still in wrong order i.e. the order in which it is in DataTable.

Comment: Odd - can you try reposting your SQL fiddle, it appears to be a different query now.

Comment: Could you post the code where you are loading the DataTable?

Comment: I had created db on another serer using script to test and there it was giving this problem, but just to test it I take backup of my db and restored it on testing server and now it started behaving normal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up your `DataTable` schema before you load it?

```
Dim table As New Data.DataTable("MyTable")

table.Columns.Add("DataName")
table.Columns.Add("33^Bamako_T")
table.Columns.Add("33^Bamako_A")

adapter.Fill( table )
```

Comment: @ThinkinStiff, not I am not it is just like DataTable dt = GetDataFromDB(); But I had created db on another serer using script to test and there it was giving this problem, but just to test it I take backup of my db and restored it on testing server and now it started behaving normal.